# Custom font not loading in CSS font-face

Tags: css, fonts

So I have a production project in laravel. The problem I'm facing is when I upload custom font to public directory (ttf, woff, woff2) and then in `.css` file specify `@font` family it does show up in CSS when I  inspect element as `font-family` but font does not actually change.

```
@font-face {
    src: url('/../fonts/custom-font.woff');
    font-family: "custom-font" !important;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: "custom-font" !important;
```

Comment: In the font declaration you call the font `custom-font.woff` but in the h1 rules you call `custom-font`... So I would expect this to not work. they need to be the same if you want this to work.

Comment: Now that you made a change to that, try without the dot.

Comment: Yep, my bad, thats's wrong but just here not in the project itself the naming is allright there xD

Comment: Also, when i inspect the page, that custom-font does not appear in network> fonts section it should right? or inspect > sources

Comment: No the browser will only fetch fonts if they have been used on the page no matter if you already declared them. Remove the dot from the font family name and try again. Dots are special in CSS land

Comment: oh gotcha, So like this? (I edit the original)

Comment: So you still got the same issue? If so check that the path to your font files is 100% correct.

Comment: Oh and you don't need `!important` in the font declaration

Comment: Maybe you mean `src: url('../fonts/custom-font.woff');` instead of `src: url('/../fonts/custom-font.woff');`

Comment: Ok we have some progress, but now this is getting wierd :D . so by the looks of it it only affects numbers? Is this even a thing? when i turn off font-family: customfont; from inspector only numbers change

Comment: That can happen when the font only has numbers in it's set.

Comment: ok, it woks now ! The problem was the god damn font. Ty so much for helping <3

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had several problems. First of all I had `!important` which was not needed, but most importantly, the font i was using was wrongly formatted.

```
     @font-face {
        src: url('/../fonts/custom-font.woff');
        font-family: "custom-font";
    }
    
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        font-family: "custom-font";
}
```

It should have been like this, and make sure you double check font you are using